# Kaa, My first application - can't retrieve collected data

Tags: mongodb, kaa

I'm doing my first kaa application, i have a stuck at Retrieve collected data step.

I have build my client project, kaa-app run as below:

```
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ 
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ 
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ 
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ 
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ 
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ 
viettq@viettq:~/Documents/workspace/kaa_example/build$ ./kaa-app 
Default sample period: 1 seconds
Sampled temperature: 33
2017/02/17 2:29:10 [WARNING] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:612] (-7) - Could not find next Bootstrap access point (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2017/02/17 2:29:10 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:307] (-7) - Kaa TCP channel [0x929A2016] error notifying bootstrap manager on access point failure
2017/02/17 2:29:10 [ERROR] [kaa_client.c:240] (-7) - Failed to process OUT event for the client socket 3
Sampled temperature: 30
Sampled temperature: 32
Sampled temperature: 26
2017/02/17 2:29:13 [WARNING] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:612] (-7) - Could not find next Bootstrap access point (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2017/02/17 2:29:13 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:307] (-7) - Kaa TCP channel [0x929A2016] error notifying bootstrap manager on access point failure
2017/02/17 2:29:13 [ERROR] [kaa_client.c:240] (-7) - Failed to process OUT event for the client socket 3
Sampled temperature: 31
Sampled temperature: 32
Sampled temperature: 31
```

Some data send to kaa sandbox server.
My ssh to kaa sandbox server as below:

```
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ 
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ mongo kaa
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: kaa
> db.logs_80610364736216152939.find()
> db.logs_80610364736216152939.find()
> db.logs_80610364736216152939.find()
> 
[2]+  Stopped                 mongo kaa
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ mongo kaa
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: kaa
> db.logs_80610364736216152939.find()
> 
> 
>
```

Nothing in mongoDB shell.

I done everything full compilance the Kaa official tutorial
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/

But i retrieve nothing from mongoDB shell.

Please help me slove it.

Thank advance!

Comment: Did you do the "use [database]" before making the query?

Comment: I checked the building process, and i cant find step to chose "use [database]", please help me find it, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs you provided:

```
2017/02/17 2:29:10 [WARNING] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:612] (-7) - Could not find next Bootstrap access point (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1) 
2017/02/17 2:29:10 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:307] (-7) - Kaa TCP channel [0x929A2016] error notifying bootstrap manager on access point failure 
2017/02/17 2:29:10 [ERROR] [kaa_client.c:240] (-7) - Failed to process OUT event for the client socket 3
```

The application can`t send information to Kaa Sandbox server. Check that you correctly created all schemas and log appender. Check that you can connect to the server.

Please also check the Sandbox configuration for the Kaa host on the Management page. There should be set the PC host (which runs the Kaa Sandbox VM) machine's IP address accessible from the host you are running the application.

Note that each time the Kaa host setting is changed, you should re-generate Kaa SDK and re-build your application with that new SDK files. Otherwise, the application might fail connecting to the Kaa operations service.